# jasper report hyperlink subreport

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, subreport

I do understand that dashboard feature is not available at community edition. Is there any way to call a drilled down report/subreport using hyperlink to a specific portion of the main report page along with the main report data ? Can frame help in this regards ?

Any help is most appriciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the hyperlink which drills down to the subreport, along with the data from the previous report.

What you need to do is that in whichever portion you want to put **hyperlink** in the main report navigate to the portion and right click on the element and there is an option

Then a window will appear, with title **HyperLink** . Then in the **Anchor Name Expression**  you need to set the path of the subreport, either the **local path** or if you want to use it over Jasper Server then the **jasper repository path** of the jrxml file of the subreport.

Then set the hyperlink type to the report execution and then and here in the **Link parameters** you could add the parameters which needs to be passed on to the subreport. Please take care of the mapping.

Then you are good to go.Hope that this Helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Ankur. I can create a hyperlink but the requirement is to open the linked report at the same report page along with the main report. So that I will get the Master report as well with the linked report.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is you want runtime, active window itself in master report which contains the subreport and displays it when a hyper link is clicked, right?

I fear that couldn't be done in the community edition.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again ankur for your time and valuable inputs. One polite query ! Can we call the called linked report in any other frame of the master report ? If yes , then how ? In this case it can bring a solution.